# The value of attribute "method-signature" associated with an element type "cc:attribute" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I got the error

> The value of attribute "method-signature" associated with an element type "cc:attribute" must not contain the '<' character.
> javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /resources/custom.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 6]

**`custom.xhtml`**

```
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute method-signature="List<String> function(String param)" name="function"/>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <p:ajax event="change" update="#{cc.attrs.function}"/>
    </composite:implementation>
</f:view>
```

The error comes from `<String>` because it's not allowed in XML to use angle brackets inside of tags. So what is the correct way to declare the method signature for the composite attribute? It's JSF 2 and Primefaces 7.0. What is the correct syntax for MethodExpression in JSF? Is generic method supported in EL? Should I escape the angle brackets using `&lt;` and `&gt;` or maybe remove the generic type and EL will parse `List function(String param)` correctly?

Comment: I am pretty sure generics are not supported in EL.

Comment: @Melloware so just `java.util.List function(java.lang.String param)`?

Comment: You have to look JSF Composites are interesting for example here is one of my declarations

`method-signature="void actionListener()"`

Comment: @Melloware you're wrong, that's not the signature I need

Comment: I wansn't suggesting that was correct I was giving you an example of a JSF CC Method Signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic methods are not supported by EL. Also, you have to provide full qualified class names as types. So the signature you need is

```
java.util.List function(java.lang.String param)
```